# Compare Value with Session and Show and Hide Menu items Based on Session Value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to hide some menu items, if the users Session has value 1 in it. But I triedmany ways, but It's still not showing up. Sorry I may sound stupid, But I am totally new to Asp.Net
And when I am trying to print the value on screen with @Session["isAdmin"] its displaying 1. So Why the if else block is not working, Please help.

```
if(Session["isAdmin"].Equals(1))
                        {
                            @Session["address"];
                        }
```

Comment: P.S. some more examples e.g. your menu-item. How you are wrapping them inside you if statement that check if `Session["isAdmin"].Equals(1)`?

Comment: I am adding @if(Session["isAdmin"])

Comment: Can you share full code please. The information you have provide in your post is clearly not sufficient for us to answer.

Comment: @if (Session["isVendor"].Equals(1))
                        {
                            @vendor;
                        }
                        else if(Session["isAdmin"].Equals(1))
                        {
                            @Session["address"];
                        }